# Blackout number in pdf using OCR

Tags: c#, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Have 3 pages PDF which has scanned Id card. Id card copy can be on any page I need to blackout Id card number (Format of Id card number - 12 Digits and two spaces i.e xxxx xxxx xxxx)

Please suggest how can i achieve this

I tried microsoft computer vision OCR services but unable to integrate the code

Need to automate this task

Find the Input and expected Output file
[Input and Outputfile](https://filebin.net/qwyjhkdvw72yzpgn)

Answer (score 0):

I would locate qrcode (there are several packages of zbar for python) and clean area below it - dimension could be calculated by qr code size...

Comment: I am unable to find QR code since it is a scanned image within a pdf can tesseract ocr can provide me co-ordinates of text with in a pdf

Comment: Can **tesseract** can give bounding box or coordinates of text elements

Comment: Yes it can. You can try to extract lined from this (I can not format is code :-( ):

    import pytesseract
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"/path/bin/tesseract"
    tessdata_dir_config = r'''--tessdata-dir "path/to/tessdata_best/tessdata"'''
    data = pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open('test2.jpg'), lang='eng', config=tessdata_dir_config,
         output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)